# Forwarding a Variable Number of Arguments to SpdLog in a C++ Module

Tags: c++, module, variadic-templates, spdlog

I am a professional C# developer and am starting a C++ side project. One of my first steps has been to get logging up and running using spdlog. As this is a new modern project, I am using modules.

I have written a Meyers Singleton class intended to encapsulate spdlog and hide it entirely within a module so that at any time in the future I could swap out a different logging library and no client code would need to be changed. Any calling code just needs to import my "Logger" wrapper module and start logging away.

The logger is part of a shared library ("Core") that uses spdlog built as a static library.

I have the basic functionality working, but I need to implement the ability to forward a variable number of arguments sent to my wrapper method to the corresponding spdlog methods (trace(), info(), etc.).

A client should be able to use the code like this:

```
import Logger;

int main()
{
    //This is a static method that calls my singleton wrapper.
    Logger::Info("{1} is a {0}", "test", "This");
}
```

When calling the `info()` member function on a spdlog instance, this call works fine. For example:

```
//This works fine calling on spdlog directly.
directSpdlogInstance->info("{1} is a {0}", "test", "This");
```

But if I try the static call on my singleton wrapper "Logger" as above, I get errors. The signature of the spdlog function I'm trying to call from within my wrapper is this:

```
template <typename... Args>
inline void info(format_string_t<Args...> fmt, Args &&...args);
```

Here are some implementations I've tried along with their errors:

```
template<typename...Args>
void Logger::Info(Args&&... args)
{
    //GetInstance() retrieves a spdlog logger instance.
    GetInstance()->info(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

When I try this I get compile error C7595:

> 'fmt::v9::basic_format_string<char,const char
> (&)[32]>::basic_format_string': call to immediate function is not a
> constant expression   Nano    C:\Dev\Nano\Projects\Core\src\Logger.cppm   30

OK. So it seems I can't simply forward the arguments. It also seems spdlog is using the `fmt` library. So I found a preprocessor #define for spdlog "SPDLOG_USE_STD_FORMAT" which seems to switch it to use the std library version of format.

With this define in place, I tried implementing it like this:

```
template<typename...Args>
void Logger::Info(std::format_string<Args...> fmt, Args&&... args)
{
    GetInstance()->info(fmt, std::make_format_args(args...));
}
```

I get compiler error C2664:

> 'void spdlog::logger::info<std::_Format_arg_store<_Context,const char
> (&)[32]>>(std::basic_format_string<char,std::_Format_arg_store<_Context,const char (&)[32]>>,std::_Format_arg_store<_Context,const char (&)[32]>
> &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from
> 'std::basic_format_string<char,const char (&)[32]>' to
> 'std::basic_format_string<char,std::_Format_arg_store<_Context,const
> char (&)[32]>>'
> with
> [
> _Context=std::format_context
> ] Nano    C:\Dev\Nano\Projects\Core\src\Logger.cppm   34

Edit: I think I've got a little further now. If I implement the function like this:

```
template<typename...Args>
void Logger::Info(std::format_string<Args...> fmt, Args&&... args)
{
    GetInstance()->info(fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

then the project compiles successfully: 0 errors, 0 warnings!

But now I get an error in the Console application project that is USING the logger. It's linker error LNK1104:

> cannot open file 'C:\Dev\Nano\bin\windows-Debug\Core\Core.lib'

My dll file is getting built, but there's no corresponding lib file now! I understand this generally happens if there's nothing that gets exported from the dll. But clearly my module code is exporting the public static method:

```
export class Logger
{
public:
    Logger(const Logger& other) = delete;

    template<typename...Args>
    NN_API static void Info(std::format_string<Args...> fmt, Args&&... args);
...
```

and the main() function is calling it as described above. NN_API is a pretty standard __declspec(dllexport) define.

I feel like I'm close but can't make it across the finish line. Can someone please help?

Comment: _" I've of course tried variadic templates in every form I can think of but can't get it to work."_ - Perhaps, if what you want to learn is how to use variadic templates, you focus on that in your question.  You've shown none of your efforts in that regard. If it's something else, remove variadic templates... Right now, I don't know where you need help. Select _one_ topic and  remove all else to make it a clear question. If you do need help interpreting error messages, you need to include them in full.

Comment: Here is a thread from previous attempts:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76824096/wrapping-a-call-to-spdlog-inside-a-variadic-macro

I am asking for someone to grab the repo and see if they can implement the single method. I have tried many variations and they all give different errors, sometimes completely unrelated to my method. Many times I'll get an error about something in the spdlog library itself, which makes no sense. I could list all of the variations I've tried and the corresponding errors I received but that would be fruitless as there are so many variations.

Comment: _"I am asking for someone to grab the repo and see if they can implement the single method"_ - You didn't read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) did you? Please formulate a free-standing question about something you need help with. "I need to build a rocket-ship, where do I start?" is not it.

Comment: Thanks for not helping, Ted. Just move on. It *is* a single question. I even posted the link to the last time I asked and didn't really get help there either.

Comment: You are I'm afraid stuck with me and my ilks. It's not to be mean. It's just to make questions into answerable questions. All the questions I've asked is meant to guide _you_ into asking in a better way. I may not be the best guide in that regard, but it's meant to be guiding anyway.

Comment: Not sure I understand what is unanswerable about my question. I'm asking how I can write a wrapper method that forwards all arguments to the wrapped library. Yes, I've Googled it and tried tons of variations and none have worked.

Comment: You've tried it for months, not read the "how to ask" guideline, yet tried to get an answer here twice, tell people who spend a lot of time here to "move on" when they try to guide you. Are you certain you are approaching this the best possible way?

Comment: OK I've reformulated the question with specifics of code that I've tried along with their errors.

Comment: - That's a brilliant rework of the question! You just got a +1

Comment: So your question is now: how to export (variadic) template function (as shared library .dll/.so). And you cannot. Can be exported as C++ modules though.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so iterating though my attempts above I ultimately reached the syntax that compiles properly, and @Jarod42 above pointed out why the function isn't exported. It's obvious in retrospect!

The reason the variadic function isn't visible to consumers of the DLL is because it's not being generated. Since this is a shared library (DLL) which is linked with a consuming application at runtime, there is no way for the compiler to know which versions of the variadic function to instantiate!

So to fix the final issue, I believe the logger will need to be turned into a static library so that all of the instantiations of the variadic function can be determined at compile time.